# chrome is slow in windows7 64bit (anything need 500ms "waiting") 

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit

under the windows7 64bit,chrome get anything,any URL,any type,and page need to "waiting" time of 500 ms

I tried below URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:6001/index.html
http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js
```

These URL have the same problems (the first URL is my localhost WEB server)

I try it in firefox,IE9(in windows7 64bit), and chrome in my windows7 32bit laptop,this problem does not exist.

This problem only occurs in my current windows7 64-bit systems computer

I try **chrome 12.0.742.100** and **chromium 14.0.794.0**,has same problem
(my chrome does not install any plug-in, without any set)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your control panel > Internet Properties > Connections > Local Area Network (LAN) settings. And un check automatically detect. See if that helps with your issue.

Let me know if that helps you  :)

NOTE: Do not try this if you are using a proxy.

[image]